# What insurances to get in Norway?

Tags: norway, insurance

I have been living in Norway for soon over a year and I was wondering what to do with insurance. I am insured at Storebrand with my employer (private pension, travel, accident) and my girlfriend has an *innboforsikring* that covers me as well.

In Germany, I know that there are certain private insurances that are a must have, like a *Haftpflichtversicherung* that covers damages you cause to others, like for example accidentally setting a house on fire. Are there insurances that you should get for yourself when living in Norway that are considered a "must-have"?

Answer (score 3):

Check the details of your *innboforsikring*, mine from Tryg includes legal expenses and private liability insurance ("Rettshjelp og privatansvar"), and I would guess other insurance companies do the same. This is the case for both their standard and "ekstra" insurance. See for instance here: http://www.tryg.no/forsikringer/innboforsikring.html

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your situation I think. If you rent a home you definitely want a good **Innbo-insurance**.

If you own a home you need to have a **Villa-insurance**. If you have kids I'd recommend Barne-insurance.

The **Travel-insurance** is vital in all cases, so if you lose that; get a private one. It covers most things that could happen while on the go; except for using a car of course.

For a car you'd want the **Delkasko-insurance** or **Fullkasko-insurance**, depending on how expensive the car is. Delkasko is fine if it's a cheap car (for you). Both cover damage to your windshield.